# Why am I not being redirected after setting a cookie

Tags: python, flask, routes

My server side code:

```
@app.route("/login_endpoint_client", methods=\["POST"\])
def authtoken():
authtok = request.get_json()
print(authtok)
data = {"cookie":"value"}
resp  = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/vote", json=data)
print(resp.text)
return authtok
```

My client side code:

```
@app.route('/vote', methods=["GET","POST"])
def vote():
    if request.method == "GET":
        cook = request.cookies.get("authcheck")
        print("cookie",cook)
        if cook == None:
            return redirect("http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/API_key1")
            
        if cook:
            return render_template("votedummy.html")

        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = request.get_json()
            resp = make_response(render_template("votedummy.html"))
            resp.set_cookie("authcheck", data['cookie'], max_age=300)
            return resp

    return render_template("vote.html")
```

Im trying to make it so that one only has to login if a cookie is not already set in the browser, in the POST block in the client side code I'm not being redirected/sent to the new page denoted by vote dummy.html.

Im trying to make it so that one only has to login if a cookie is not already set in the browser, in the POST block in the client side code I'm not being redirected/sent to the new page denoted by vote dummy.html.

Instead the cookie is being sent back to the server side instead of just being set to all routes and im resent back to the same page instead of rerouted to the new votedummy.html

Whats the issue?
Could you please help, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but it seems to me that 'if request.method == 'POST':' is never reached.

Above it there are; 'If cook == None: return...' and then 'If cook retrun...'
Soo the code below that will only be reached when cook is == False, but I suspect that it is never a False.